# docker build in run time or docker compose from images

Tags: image, docker, docker-compose

In my work place we hv a docker reg, which among others have a DB image and source-code image. We also have some static-data in source control..(not made into a docker image though..yet).. I would like to combine these three things to hv a docker env..That is my goal.

To do this, I see two options.

1) create a data-only image for the static data, get it pushed to the registry and this data image can be mounted on the already exisitng DB image to have what I want (env build in run time)

2) build another image from DB with the static-data push this new image to a registry and use this new image along with the source-code image to have this env. (not a lot happening in run-time as env is built from known and stable images)

which is the best approach ? any other suggestions ? I just to build a DB from an alresy exisitng DB image and need to add static data (mainatned in source control) on top of to create a new env..what is the best approach for this purpose pls ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't well understand your goals, but here's some common practices.

1. Build an image on top on other things.
   Use this when extending a software, like, installing plugins.
   You can replace `image` with `build` syntax to build it from Dockerfile locally. You don't need to publish it to remote registry.
2. Combine multiple image, and connect them with network.
   Build a separate image for your backend server, then connect it with a SQL server with Docker private networking.

Comment: Hi Thanks..I see these are common approaches...let me be clear about what my goal here is...in my work place we hv a docker reg, which among others have a DB image and source-code image. We also have some data in source control..(not made into a docker image though..yet).. I would like to combine these three things to hv a docker env..That is my goal.. The question is how best I can achieve this...look at my approaches above and tell me which is best and if there is any other better way..thanks

Comment: any1  could u kind enough to shed some light pls ?

Comment: I have already mentioned that you can use a Dockerfile to add immutable data on top on other Docker images.

Comment: hi thanks..but how exactly is to add the data ? u mean mount docker volumes....mount dir etc..please be specific and if you can give an example of such dockerfile..thanks

Comment: You know Dockerfile and you can't even use the basic ADD?

Comment: no need to shout..if u do not want to give explanatory answer,,do not give answer for the sake of it..I am not even sure you understood the question..please refrain from giving plain answers...thanks...

Comment: Read [the](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#build) [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/).